# Lambda between two dates explicit

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, lambda

I am in need of some wizards.

I have a table

```
Start                 End                   PersonID
-----------------------------------------------------
10/07/2017 00:00:00   18/07/2017 00:00:00   1
27/07/2017 00:00:00   27/07/2017 00:00:00   1
28/07/2017 00:00:00   28/07/2017 00:00:00   1
29/07/2017 00:00:00   29/07/2017 00:00:00   1
30/07/2017 00:00:00   30/07/2017 00:00:00   1
```

If I search for

```
Date Start = 11/07/2017
Date End = 12/07/2017
```

Using this query:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2017,07,11,0,0,0,0,0);
DateTime end = start.AddDays(1);
DateTime[] days = new DateTime[end.Subtract(start).Days];

for (int i = 0; i < end.Subtract(start).Days; i++)
{
     var d = start.AddDays(i);
     days[i] = d;
}

IQueryable block = tmOpen1.Calendar.Where(x => days.All(y => y >= x.start && y <= x.end)).Select(x => new { ID = x.PersonID });`
```

I get a positive result for ROW 1 (10/07/2017 - 18/07/2017)

However If I apply it against the remaining rows e.g. Filter

```
Date Start = 28/07/2017
Date End = 29/07/2017
```

Then obviously this will fail.  How Can I get this side of the search to work.

E.g. Either

1. Take the first row and make it split out into individual rows
2. Make the Individual rows return true if a Person has several true conditions.

I hope one of the geniuses here can help.

Comment: It's confusing what you are asking for. Do you just want to filter rows that overlap the dates provided?

Comment: `Then obviously this will fail.` It is not obvious to us. Does it fail? Should it fail? What **should** it return?

Comment: If I request two dates I need it to return the dates that overlap those in the Database.  With a person.  - Problem is that some rows are a range of dates and others are individual

Comment: What you need to do is check that the start date in the table > 28/07/2017 (Date Start) and the start date in table < 29/07/2017 (Date End)

Comment: @TheMonkeyMan, May you check my answer. Because your expected result for '11/07/2017' and '28/07/2017' are not clear.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like all you really need is something like this:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2017,07,11,0,0,0,0,0);
DateTime end = start.AddDays(1);

var results = tmOpen1.Calendar
    .Where(c => start <= c.end && end >= c.start)
    .Select(x => new { ID = x.PersonID });
```

Comment: Yeah, this one is simpler.

Comment: But for `27/07/2017 00:00:00   27/07/2017 00:00:00   1`, `27/07/2017 <= 12/07/2017` => false and `27/07/2017 >= 11/07/2017`=> true. That's not good.

Comment: @DragandDrop Ugh, I got dragged into a meeting before I could test. Have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If your interval starts or ends somewhere between a start and end date from the table, than it means it is overlapping and you should included in your result.

```
tmOpen1.Calendar.Where(x => (startDate >= x.start && startDate <= x.end) || (endDate >= x.start && endDate <= x.end)).Select(x => new { ID = x.PersonID });
```

So an interval 10.07 - 27.07 should give you the first 2 rows, right?

Or is the interval supposed to be fully enclosed between 2 dates in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Simplier with the not valid time frame:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2017, 07, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = start.AddDays(1);

var results = tmOpen1.Calendar.
                    .Where( c => ! ( c.Start > end  ||  c.End < start) )
                    .Select(x => new { ID = x.PersonID } );
```

For `DateTime start = new DateTime(2017, 07, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);`
The result are:

```
TEST 1: 11/07/2017 00:00:00
  Start:10/07/2017 00:00:00       End:18/07/2017 00:00:00       ID:1
```

For `DateTime start = new DateTime(2017, 07, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);`
The result are:

```
TEST 2: 28/07/2017 00:00:00
  Start:28/07/2017 00:00:00       End:28/07/2017 00:00:00       ID:1
  Start:29/07/2017 00:00:00       End:29/07/2017 00:00:00       ID:1
```

Comment: From my understanding, Op requirement are:  For date = 11/07/2017 1rst line of dataset must be return. For date = 28/07/2017 3rd and 4rth are the good one.

Answer (score 0):

From understanding of your question you want to know when the `Date Start` or `Date End` is within a range of dates.

You can check `Date Start` is within the date range or the `Date End` is within the date range

Example:

```
List<DateRange> dates = new List<DateRange>();
dates.Add(new DateRange()
{
    StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 10),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 18)
});

dates.Add(new DateRange()
{
    StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 28),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 28)
});

DateRange search1 = new DateRange()
{
    StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 11),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 12)
};

DateRange search2 = new DateRange()
{
    StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 28),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 29)
};

var result1 =  dates.Where(x => search1.StartDate >= x.StartDate && search1.StartDate <= x.EndDate || 
                search1.EndDate <= x.StartDate && search1.EndDate >= x.EndDate);

var result2 = dates.Where(x => search2.StartDate >= x.StartDate && search2.StartDate <= x.EndDate ||
                search2.EndDate <= x.StartDate && search2.EndDate >= x.EndDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

modelclassList= modelclassList.Where(x => x.gf_expdate>DateTime.Now).ToList();

to check expiry date and save back list of model class